# Why isn't {-able} considered a free morpheme?

Tags: grammar, style-manuals, morphemes

So the question is that if the morpheme, {-able}, is considered a *bound morpheme*, however, I am not sure why it cannot be used by itself and be considered a *free morpheme*, i.e. I am *able* to do this. Also, it is pronounced, *ible* and not *able*. But why?

Thanks.

Comment: It's pronounced _-ible_ and not _able_ because it's a suffix, not a free morpheme. Suffixes are often pronounced in ways different from lexical words. And it's a bound morpheme because when it's pronounced this way it's always attached to something, and never appears free. The fact that it's often spelled the same as the adjective _able_ doesn't make it the same morpheme; it's never pronounced the same. Also, the suffix, but not the lexical item, is often spelled _-ible_, not _-able_, though it's pronounced the same however it's spelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word “able” is certainly a free morpheme. The relevant question is whether “able” and “-able” represent the same morpheme. The identical spellings are actually somewhat of a coincidence, as they have different etymologies. The “-ble” parts have the same origin, but the A's don't: the word *able* is from Latin *hăbĭl-,* which came from the verb *hăbeo* + the suffix *-bĭl-* (one of the B's was apparently lost by haplology), while the suffix *-able* is from Latin *-ābĭl-,* which came from the suffix *-bĭl-* combined with the A-vowel that occurred at the end of "first-conjugation" verb stems.

But I don’t think etymology by itself is a full explanation for why “-able” would be analyzed as a different morpheme from “able”.

I think it’s relevant that the distribution of “-able” looks like the distribution of a bound morpheme/affix: there are words where it triggers a (sometimes optional) stress shift, such as “preferable”, and there are words where it combines with a bound morpheme, or at least a specialized allomorph that cannot occur freely, such as “despic-“ in “despicable”.